# Big Sur - Homebrew Install - illegal variable name

Tags: install, homebrew, big-sur

Trying to install Homebrew on Big Sur 11.2.3

Using:
`/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`
in my Terminal

Getting:
`"Illegal variable name"`

The above code installed fine on a VM of High Sierra an hour ago. so I know it works

Anyone have any ideas why it is not working on Big Sur?

Answer (score 6):

You need to [install homebrew](https://brew.sh) with this command:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Note: Use `/bin/bash` rather than `/usr/bin/ruby`.

The `curl` command inside the `$()` expression is executed and returns the content of the `install.sh` file. Then, the shell replaces the `$()` expression with these install instructions. As the install instructions are written for `bash` rather than `ruby`, `bash` is needed to execute them.

I could not reproduce the "illegal variable name" issue, however. Therefore, here are a couple of other workarounds that might help:

### Option 1: Switch to bash or zsh

The "illegal variable name" could occur if you are not using `bash` or `zsh` as your terminal shell, but `csh` or `tcsh` instead. (You could find out using `echo $0`.)

Try switching to `bash` or `zsh` before executing the install command:

```
/bin/zsh
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

The first line starts a `zsh` shell. (You can also try `/bin/bash` instead, but I think, Big Sur uses `zsh` by default, now.) Then the second line is executed in this shell, which should circumvent the "illegal variable name" error.

The reason is that the `bash` and `zsh` shells might handle the `$()` expansion differently than `csh` and `tcsh`. If `csh` interprets everything after the `$` as variable, it might consider `$(...` is an illegal variable name.

### Option 2: Install from downloaded file

If, as mentioned in the comments, you have already downloaded the `install.sh` file, try executing the following in your terminal:

```
/bin/bash /path/to/install.sh
```

Here, `/path/to/install.sh` needs to be replaced by the actual path of the downloaded file. You could just type `/bin/bash`  and then drag-and-drop the file to your terminal, which should insert the path.

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same response "illegal variable name"

Comment: I can obviously go to "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)" and save the file as "Install.sh" - Can I then install it locally in some way?

Comment: This sounds like maybe you're using `csh` or `tcsh` as shell rather than `bash` or `zsh`, which might be the root of the "illegal variable name" error. Could you post the result of `echo $0`, which shows the shell your terminal is using. Regarding the installation from the downloaded `install.sh`, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Option 2 did the trick!!! thanks so much...

/bin/bash /path/to/install.sh running the downloaded sh file worked

option 1 did not, though it seems like it should have done, but no matter!!!

Comment: Great! Could you still post what `echo $0` returns?

Comment: sure, sorry, here it is:

[TRITON-xxxx:~] xxx% echo $0
-tcsh